# How to write/read a (pickled) array of strings in sql using df.to_sql?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to append scrape data while the scrape is running.

Some of the columns contain an array of multiple strings which are to be saved and postprocessed into dummies after the scrape.
e.g tags= array(['tag1','tag2'])

However writing to and reading from the database doesn't work for the arrays.

Ive tried different storage methods, csv, pickling, HDF all of these dont work for different reasons.
(mainly problems appending to a central database and storing lists like strings).
I also tried different database formats (mysql and postgres) , i tried using dtype ARRAY, however that requires a fixed length (known beforehand) array..

From what i gather, i can go the JSON route or the pickle route.
I chose the pickle route since i dont need the db to do anything with the contents of the array.

```
from sqlalchemy.types import PickleType

df=pd.DataFrame([],columns=['Name','Tags'])
df['Price'] = array(['tag1','tag2'], dtype='<U8')

type_dict = {'Name': String ,'Tags': PickleType}

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)

df.to_sql('test', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, dtype=type_dict)

df2=pd.read_sql_table('test' ,con =engine)
```

expected output:

```
df2['Tags'].values
array(['tag1','tag2'], dtype='<U8')
```

actual output:

```
df2['Tags'].iloc[0] 
b'\x80\x04\x95\xa4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x15numpy.core.multiarray\x94\x8c\x0c_reconstruct\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x05numpy\x94\x8c\x07ndarray\x94\x93\x94K\x00\x85\x94C\x01b\x94\x87\x94R\x94(K\x01K\x01\x85\x94h\x03\x8c\x05dtype\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x02U8\x94K\x00K\x01\x87\x94R\x94(K\x03\x8c\x01<\x94NNNK K\x04K\x08t\x94b\x89C \xac \x00\x00\xac \x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\xac \x00\x00\xac \x00\x00\xac \x00\x00\x94t\x94b.'
```

So something has gone wrong during pickling, and I cant figure out what.

edit:
Okay, so np.loads(df2['Tags'].iloc[0]) gives the original array back. Is there a way to pass this to read_sql_table? such that i immediately get the "original" dataframe back?

So the problems occurs during the reading, the arrays are pickled, but they are not automatically read back as pickled data. There is no way to pass dtype to read_sql_table right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def unpickle_the_pickled(df):
    df2=df
    for col in df.columns:
        if type(df[col].iloc[0])==bytes:
            df2[col]=df[col].apply(np.loads)

    return df2
```

finally solved it, so happy!